# Nested Accordion expand full First pane jquery

Tags: jquery

I have requirement for following output.

item 1
 item 1.1
   item 1.1.1
 item 1.2
item 2
item 3
if i click on item 2 then output will be
item 1
item 2
 item 2.1
  item 2.1.1
 item 2.2
item 3

Here is my javascript.

```
$(".slide-list li a").click(function() {    

        if ($(this).hasClass("selected") && $(this).next().queue().length === 0) {
            $(this).next().slideUp();
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
        } 
    else if (!$(this).hasClass("selected") && $(this).next().queue().length === 0) {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        //$(this).next().find("ul:first").show();
        $(this).next().find("ul:first").slideToggle('slow'); //not working perfectly.    
        }
     var $licurrent = $(this).parent();
     window.location.hash = $('.slide-list li').index($licurrent);
$licurrent.parent().find("li").not($licurrent).find("a").removeClass("selected");           $licurrent.parent().find("li").not($licurrent).find("ul").hide("k");

 });

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Accord-wrapper ul.slide-list li a").first().trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lovethakker/4YWJU/)

Comment: Yes, what *is* your question *exactly*? Also you need to sort out the matching of brackets in your HTML, it's showing as a mess in your fiddle.

Comment: I assume he wants to expand not only "submenu item 1.1 level 2", but "submenu item 1.1 level 3" as well.

Comment: i have updated my question so you can have better idea of my requirement. I want to open first pane only for each level hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**:

If you want to show level 2 and level 3 instead of level 2 only, here is the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4YWJU/10/)..

Change your JS into this:

```
$(".slide-list li a").click(function() { 
    if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
        temp_selector = $(this).next("ul");
        while(temp_selector.length > 0 ){
            temp_selector.slideUp();
            temp_selector = temp_selector.find("ul");
        } 
    }else{
        $(this).parent().siblings("li").each(function(){
            $(this).find(".selected").next("ul").slideUp();
            $(this).find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        });
        temp_selector = $(this).next("ul");
        while(temp_selector.length > 0 ){
            temp_selector.prev("a").addClass("selected");
            temp_selector.slideDown();
            temp_selector = temp_selector.children("li").first().children("a").next("ul");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: in this example the panes are opening everything. i want only first level. and panes are not closing when i click to second item. can u suggest something for it?

Comment: still pane are not closing when click on other menu item. and now the sub menu item hierarchy also not opening.

Comment: According to your title then this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4YWJU/9/) should give what you want..

Comment: very close. the sub menu item 1.2 clicked then everything collapse. can u do something for that?

Comment: I just updated my answer above to fit your goal.. Remember that usually we don't answer too specific question like yours.. So, next time try to ask a general question.. Hope it helps..